# gtkmm x events are not working

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am trying to handle x events for a drawing area widget so the user can pan around and draw on it. Press event and release event handlers are called but not the motion notify event. I added `Gdk::POINTER_MOTION_MASK` and overrode `on_motion_notify_event(GdkEventButton *event)` handler but it doesn't get called. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did *exactly* what you stated, the problem is that you overloaded the right method name, but the wrong argument type.  The correct overload is this (from the docs):

```
  virtual bool Gtk::Widget::on_motion_notify_event(GdkEventMotion * event)
```

Note the different argument type.